# Should I use gasoline 87, 89 or 93 on 2016 RAV4 SE

Tags: toyota, gasoline, octane, rav4

I read many articles online and people have different opinions about this issue.  Some say 89 is the best for acceleration.  Others say 87 is just fine.

I'm worried only about the health of my car.  So I read my user manual. Here are the screenshots.  I'm not sure, but SE probably stands for sport edition.  So should I use better than 87? I just want to use whatever is best for my RAV4's health.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What country do you live in? Barely can find 91 anymore in Australia and I certainly wouldn't put in anything less than 10 years old.

Comment: U.S. California

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Realistically, if the manual and the manufacturer are stating you should use 87 octane, *that's really what you should use*. If you purchase more expensive 89, 91, or 93, you are just wasting money. The higher the octane rating, the harder it is for fuel to burn (or ignite). If the vehicle was specified to use 93, then that's what you should buy or you risk engine damage. You run no risk to the engine by running what the manufacturer says. You'll also gain no performance advantage from running the higher octane, mainly because the engine (and computer tune) are not designed to use it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm confused because  the manual (in the images above) says `87 (Research Octane Number 91) or higher`. And that is bothering me. If it was only 87,  then it would say 87 period. Why would they mention 91 at all ? –

Comment: @Emily - No worries. After five minutes you cannot edit the comments anyway.

Comment: @Emily - Remember when you go to the gas station, the main octane rating you see is actually an average of two different types of octane ratings, one is the RON or Research Octane Number and the other is MON or Motor Octane Number. These are two different lines of thought, but are averaged to come up with what you see at the pump. Your book is stating for RON, which I assume is so it can be looked at in other countries which may only use the RON for the fuels there.

Comment: Okay so I guess 87 is for the U.S. customers like myself, and 91 is for `outside of U.S, maybe Japan`. I've never seen 91 anyway . All gas station I've ever visited have 87,89 and 93. So, I'll go with 87, as you recommend. Thank You!

Comment: many countries outside of the US use RON only at the pump. Much of europe, australia and new zealand from personal experience all use RON. So yes, the manual states both to avoid having to print two manuals

Comment: @Emily, gas stations in higher elevations offer a different range of octanes; in Colorado it's typically 85, 87, & 91.

Comment: It's really good to know. I've never been in Colorado. I thought all of America uses the standard 87 and up

Comment: They say 87 or higher because putting higher rated gasoline in the car will only harm your pocketbook, not your car.  If they simply said "87" and someone who didn't understand what's really going on pulls into a station that only had 89 available they need to understand that it's ok to pump that.

Comment: @Emily you can find 85 in higher elevations throughout the rockies.  It's sold at elevation because the lower oxygen content of thinner air effectively derates your engine's performance and you can avoid premature ignition with a lower octane fuel as a result (eg an 87 car running on 85, or an 89 being able to run on 87).  The main caveat is that you only want to buy it when you're confident of using the entire tank without descending to a lower elevation when you'd again need the higher octane fuel.

Comment: @Emily California is 87, 89, 91.

Answer (score 4):

The acid test is if you try a lower octane fuel, if you hear any "knocking" sounds under hard acceleration (perhaps up a hill), then you definitely need a higher octane rating.  As Paulster2 mentions, there will *not* be any performance improvement, in spite of what a lot of people say.  The octane rating is just a measure of resistance to knocking.  I have a 2003 Toyota Celica GT-S that recommends premium and it runs fine on mid-grade, saving me $2.00 or more on every tank of gas.

Comment: this isn't entirely true for more recent vehicles. You won't notice knocking until you're completely outside the range the ECU can compensate for by detuning the engine. What you'll probably notice first is loss of power and fuel efficiency if you're feeding it too low an octane.

Comment: How is it possible that a 2003 Toyota requires a higher grade gas than the 2016 RAV4 ?

Comment: Most likely, because during those 13 years the fuel supply industry moved towards supplying lower octane gasoline, with a higher proportion of biofuel additives like ethanol. (I'm not in the US so I don't know the exact details of the situation there). The first major shift to lower octane fuels was when lead additives became illegal, but the trend has continued downwards since then. You can *design* an engine to run on pretty much any octane rating - the important factor is what is most commonly available at the pumps, in the country where it is going to be driven.

Comment: ... For example in the UK, the "standard grade" is 95 RON, with 97 widely available for "high performance" cars, and much more limited availability of 99, which is only sold by one national chain of gas stations, and by one of the "big four" UK supermarket chains.

Comment: @Emily Because a GT-S is a sports car with a sport-tuned engine, while the Rav4 is not.

Answer (score 2):

87 will work, 89 is optimal, 93 will also work but uses a bit more (will start to run leaner but the computer easily compensates but using more fuel) 87 better for winter (no difference over 89), 89 better for summer (helps when underhood is HOT when you have the A/C running AND trying to keep the engine around operating temp.

I would maybe avoid the absolute cheapest/oldest gas stations as there might be water/rust contamination issues. That would pose a greater threat to your engines health than just running 87 all the time.

Comment: Thank you +1. You say 89 is optimal? Do you mean 89 is ideal for the "car's health" ?

Comment: @Emily a higher octane fuel will reduce the possibility of preignition, which will occur with 87 octane under certain conditions, and possibly even with 89. The engine computer will adjust if preignition is detected by adjusting timing and reducing engine output. Conditions are heat and load dependent, more of either requires a higher octane rating to prevent preignition at the same degree of ignition timing.

Comment: Could you elaborate how you decided that 89 is somehow optimal? Manufacturer recommends 87 and up, what makes you think 87 is not optimal? And why would 93 be lean? And @RichieFrame, how are you so sure that 87 will preignite on this specific car?

Comment: @RichieFrame If the engine was designed for 87, there already is no possibility for preignition with fuel rated 87.

Comment: @Agent_L what makes you think it was designed specifically for 87? Because the manual says "87 or higher" ? Modern engines are complex machines designed to minimize preignition under a wide range of typical conditions, but it is certainly possible to operate outside of those conditions, in which case the engine will detect preignition, and adjust timing to compensate. Imagine a hot engine, 115F air temp, going up a hill, while pulling a full trailer

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing I am not sure it will preignite. Op may never experience any condition which will cause 87 or even 85 to preignite, but given the compression ratio of the engine and the type of vehicle I am inclined to believe that preignition (PI) conditions are more likely than not, one needs to take those conditions into account. I can run 89 octane in my car during the cold of winter without PI, but require 93 in the summer and sometimes experience PI at top gear full throttle (turbo engine, manual says 91 or higher)

Answer (score 1):

If the manual says 87 octane (or higher), that is all you need to run, 87 octane gas. The engine is designed to run at that octane rating optimally. You can run higher octane gasoline, but all you are doing is spending money you don't need to spend. My daughters Acura TL requires 93 octane fuel and running less impacts performance and can ping. My Ecoboost twin turbo is designed for 87 octane fuel and runs perfect all day long as it was designed to run on 87 Octane. Towing a camper makes no difference as the computer compensates. Higher octane for towing would help but isn't necessary ass the computer compensates for the octane fuel used. You can go higher, but shouldn't go lower than the minimum required.

Sunoco used to have a pump with five grades of fuel years ago all the way down to 85 octane (could blend 85, 87, 89, 91 and 93 at the pump). Sunoco 85 Octane would be used only for low compression engines or at the time, people trying to save some money as it was the least expensive fuel then.

Use a good grade 87 octane fuel and save your money.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using `89` . I have 2015 RAV4 . 89 does  give  you a better acceleration, you are right.

So go with 89 . This is the golden average .  Your manual says 87 or higher . So anything above 87 is okay. However, i wouldn't go with 93 . Be cautious 93 may result in unburnt fuel that is not very good

Comment: Did you actually do a 0-60 test, or do you *think* 89 gives you better acceleration?

Answer (score -2):

Every modern (fuel injected) car will run fine on any type of gasoline you can get on a decent gas station. The car has an engine computer that adjusts many parameters multiple times per second to get optimal performance no matter the temperature, air pressure, octane rating, throttle position, hill slope etc.

A different octane rating may make a very small difference in mileage or peak performance. I personally tank the cheapest. Never experienced any measurable difference.

The manufacturer probably has to put octane rating in the manual to get certification right (otherwise someone would tank 50% water and sue, claiming that is runs sluggish...).

Comment: That's just wrong.

Comment: Terrible answer. Yes, a car ECU considers many parameters but to suggest that it considers all ranges of parameters is just wrong.